# Angular CLI add a script outside of node_modules

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a problem with adding a script to Angular 2 with ng cli outside of the node_modules folder. The script doesn't exist ( or at least I didn't find it ) in the npm registries and it's just a single file I wish to load but cannot:

This is in angular-cli.json :

```
"scripts": [
    "assets/one-signal-sdk.js"
],
```

This throws a syntax error, saying:

"Unexpected token ? in JSON at position 0"

But, if I manually add the package to node_modules and load it like this:

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/one-signal/one-signal-sdk.js"
],
```

It's working perfectly fine. Of course, I cannot just add it manually and leave it there because no one will be able to download it via npm install.

Is there a way to add a custom script to the build? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work fine

```
"scripts": [
    "assets/one-signal-sdk.js"
],
```

Try to put in this file something simple like `document.write("test");`. If that works, the problem is specific to the content of `one-signal-sdk.js`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it seems the problem is indeed in the script I'm adding to the page. That's strange because it's working fine when added from node_modules :(

EDIT: I fixed my problem my adding the script tag to the html:

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/one-signal-sdk.js"></script>

Adding it like this doesn't throw an error in the build process. Thanks for your response :)